# Win probability of runners in a race

Tags: probability, distributions

This is a problem discussed here before.
We know the mean times of the runners (μ(i)) and the standard deviations (σ(i))) and we want to find the probabilities p(1), p(2) ... p(N).
Here is a solution:

[https://www.untruth.org/~josh/math/normal-min.pdf](https://www.untruth.org/%7Ejosh/math/normal-min.pdf)

This is a complicated looking integral but with either Simpson's rule or Monte Carlo can be evaluated easily.
My problem is to -perhaps- find a faster way.

So I try to take the runners two at a time and from the pairwise probabilities compute the
final probabilities.

The integral in the link assumes that the normal distribution is applicable, i.e. for each runner the times from start to finish are distributed normally about the mean.
But I 'm not going to use the normal distribution. I use the Laplace distribution which enables me to derive some analytical formulas. Although this changes the Physics of the problem it does n't change the mathematics.

Then for two Laplace distributed variables t(i), t(j) with μ(i), σ(i) and μ(j), σ(j) respectively the following formula holds:

a) If σ(i) = σ(j) = σ

Q(i,j) = 1 - Exp((-z / σ) * (2 + (z / σ)) / 4

b) if σ(i) <> σ(j%)

Q(i,j) = 1 - 0.5 * (Exp(-z / σ(i)) / σ(j) ^ 2 - Exp(-z / σ(j)) / σ(i) ^ 2) / (1 / σ(j) ^ 2 - 1 / σ(i) ^ 2)

where z = μ(j) - μ(i)

Now let's do an example with three participants:
It's a five furlong race (1000 meters) and:

μ(1) = 57.00 secs, σ(1) = 0.50 secs
μ(2) = 57.30 secs, σ(2) = 0.60 secs
μ(3) = 57.70 secs, σ(3) = 1.00 sec

Using the above formula:

Q(1,2) = 0.6311446
Q(2,3) = 0.6207114
Q(1,3) = 0.7100428

(and Q(2,1) = 1 - Q(1,2), Q(3,2) = 1 - Q(2,3), Q(3,1) = 1 - Q(1,3))

From those I mean to compute P(1), P(2) and P(3), the final probabilities of horse 1, horse 2, horse 3 to win the race.

But before I do that, I use Monte Carlo to compute P(1), P(2), P(3) and what Monte Carlo finds is the undisputed true result.

If x stands for the machine generated random number (in (0,1)) the Laplace distributed t variables are:

t(i) = μ(i) + σ(i) . f(x)

where:

f(x) = - ln(2.(1 - x)) for x >= 1/2 , ln(2.x) for x < 1/2

and the shortest t value of the three wins the trial.

I do 1000000 trials and find:

P(1) = 0.49
P(2) = 0.29
P(3) = 0.22

Now back to the pair method.
I reckon the race of the three runners is equivalent to the following type of race:

- No 3 stays out, no 1 and no 2 run against each other and the day after tomorrow the winner of 1 v 2 runs against the 3.

or

- No 2 stays out, no 1 and no 3 run against each other and the day after tomorrow the winner of 1 v 3 runs against the 2.

or

- No 1 stays out, no 2 and no 3 run against each other and the day after tomorrow the winner of 2 v 3 runs against the 1.

As these three cases are equivalent I get:

P(1) = ( 2 . Q(1,2) . Q(1,3) + Q(2,3) . Q(1,2) + Q(3,2) . Q(1,3) ) / 3 = 0.5191164
P(2) = ( 2 . Q(2,1) . Q(2,3) + Q(1,3) . Q(2,1) + Q(3,1) . Q(2,3) ) / 3 = 0.2999295
P(3) = ( 2 . Q(3,1) . Q(3,2) + Q(1,2) . Q(3,1) + Q(2,1) . Q(3,2) ) / 3 = 0.1809541

Those add to 1 but as you can see there is a discrepancy and it's a mystery.
The question is why ?

It's something I don't understand.
For suppose it was not horses but football teams and the Q values were known from ELO
rating considerations.
So with three football teams X-Y-Z it's a three cornered fight, but we 'd have to draw
them X v. Y maybe then winner against Z and the Q values give the probabilities.
It does n't look like a different problem to find the probabilities of X-Y-Z winning the trophy.

Comment: Although it's difficult to determine what you are asking, it looks like you are trying to evaluate a multidimensional integral by computing some kind of sequence of 2D marginal integrals.  There's no reason to suppose that would work either generally or in this special case of multivariate Normal distributions.

Comment: Now I understand then what I 'm trying to do is an approximation really.
Maybe a good approximation.
The multidimensional integral takes into account more information and it's more accurate.
To expand to more than three participants (N = 3,4,5,6 ...) one must make successive pair eliminations.
It works up to a point. But if N is big, e.g. N = 30, it does n't - long time to compute.

Comment: The larger $N$ is, the *worse* any such approximation will become.  This is apparent in the [curse of dimensionality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=curse%20of%20dimensionality%20score%3a5&searchOn=3).